# Alexa Skill Immediate Timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating an Alexa skill that is in essence a questionnaire. In the developer simulator on amazon's website, it works reasonably well without timeout. Following research, I've come to realize that there's a mandatory 8 second timeout approximately. I also see that in settings for the aws lambda function, one can change the timeout from a default of three seconds all the way up to five minutes, which I have done as part of my troubleshooting. However, this change seems to have had no effect.

My problem is as follows:

when testing on the alexa app or on echoism.io (I don't have an Alexa device but would imagine that these would behave similarly to it), the questions Alexa asks can only be answered if interrupted. In other words, suppose the question was finished being asked. Then, a beeping noise comes up to indicate that the user should respond. In this case, nothing happens and the skill exits even if user input is reasonable. However, if at any time during the prompt, the user hits the speak button and answers the question, interrupting the prompt, the answer will be correctly recorded as in the developer console simulation and as intended.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

**Request**

```
{
       'version':'1.0',
       'session':{
          'new':False,
          'sessionId':'amzn1.echo-api.session.f55b0102-a3cb-4c1a-9b0c-6ef73f579c69',
          'application':{
             'applicationId':'amzn1.ask.skill.20852205-3919-4d6a-8a62-cb6f8c6214ef'
          },
          'user':{
             'userId':'amzn1.ask.account.AHVXIGHORW6PSATGYB6KWTZFBJ64Q2XXGRX3KFWWTRV7KLUAYSSR657SD74Z6E5PHXF35R75SZ7GJITERAT3XZ73LRXLR4KH2552NLMAL6WMAK2NQUZQ3EXB6DGOU2BZOTXFTT4UBBQSNNXB4J74U44UNWH6QJCWYBBATIIPE6YLV7W3TP4EYWQBTNTJ3LBVXF2EGFRDYRPTUCA'
          }
       },
       'context':{
          'System':{
             'application':{
                'applicationId':'amzn1.ask.skill.20852205-3919-4d6a-8a62-cb6f8c6214ef'
             },
             'user':{
                'userId':'amzn1.ask.account.AHVXIGHORW6PSATGYB6KWTZFBJ64Q2XXGRX3KFWWTRV7KLUAYSSR657SD74Z6E5PHXF35R75SZ7GJITERAT3XZ73LRXLR4KH2552NLMAL6WMAK2NQUZQ3EXB6DGOU2BZOTXFTT4UBBQSNNXB4J74U44UNWH6QJCWYBBATIIPE6YLV7W3TP4EYWQBTNTJ3LBVXF2EGFRDYRPTUCA'
             },
             'device':{
                'deviceId':'amzn1.ask.device.AHO5K5QILDUNW7BKDBJMLWENV7INXNFAHIAUB6ELHJ66MVMKQUPFT77GEEILVUDLABIN2JNUUQGPCOW2K6FX2EFTVKAZHGYFEFHZOLSZK5SHAQHLUK624DFPDS2FBBR6X4AZTKFLIJNLOCAWVQSLW5K2YJ5PGMGT2JBYXSNJE7GZWFIZC7WYK',
                'supportedInterfaces':{

                }
             },
             'apiEndpoint':'https://api.amazonalexa.com',
             'apiAccessToken':'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.CPFDpKzKMBq9Dyhlw7S_fIHTkxN2YODIg-T85YMRWMqHQbalCFd2nC1rqOXoIAX-T6TTkKiXpOSsvEBgnERKivzPgXTRFou3dxsXijSyr4-ip2Ouu5rk-9lQ0IfVtnD424Kbezq7UzlSeEqyvblaOw4Yd7JwbTD0EuPUtCaj_pwLZny3i5-NunFdy1ytmGPN3KTsIIBjkpal61Ao_xNGgEYq_t5lOIwtEfx8uzPIO3VXn78IVC37FOEgylX3sWljGoxDyG_dQ36sprXWIdHBU0SvFnYJYntNwFH4i59KB2G3XseIcjtKDT2oN2VGF-eBdeolQ9_V_qWxqgOooYhNHw'
          }
       },
       'request':{
          'type':'IntentRequest',
          'requestId':'amzn1.echo-api.request.848c8eed-7f47-4e32-a214-e034f03caf54',
          'timestamp':'2018-07-30T15:56:15Z',
          'locale':'en-US',
          'intent':{
             'name':'ScheduleCall',
             'confirmationStatus':'NONE',
             'slots':{
                'OMProductName':{
                   'name':'OMProductName',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidSymtomsReAppear':{
                   'name':'DidSymtomsReAppear',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'ProvideHCPContactInfo':{
                   'name':'ProvideHCPContactInfo',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PatientFirstName':{
                   'name':'PatientFirstName',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskWhenEventBegun':{
                   'name':'AskWhenEventBegun',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidHCPRecommendAnyTreatment':{
                   'name':'DidHCPRecommendAnyTreatment',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PNursing':{
                   'name':'PNursing',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PDueDate':{
                   'name':'PDueDate',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PlanToContinue':{
                   'name':'PlanToContinue',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'HowOftenUseProduct':{
                   'name':'HowOftenUseProduct',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMPDose':{
                   'name':'OMPDose',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DateOfMiscarriage':{
                   'name':'DateOfMiscarriage',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WhatDateWasPAdmitted':{
                   'name':'WhatDateWasPAdmitted',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskIfFirstTime':{
                   'name':'AskIfFirstTime',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WhenStartUsingProduct':{
                   'name':'WhenStartUsingProduct',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PAnyMedicalConditions':{
                   'name':'PAnyMedicalConditions',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DrugNameSQ':{
                   'name':'DrugNameSQ',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidPatientReUseProduct':{
                   'name':'DidPatientReUseProduct',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OtherMedications':{
                   'name':'OtherMedications',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskPermission':{
                   'name':'AskPermission',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'ReportedCauseOfDeath':{
                   'name':'ReportedCauseOfDeath',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMPFreq':{
                   'name':'OMPFreq',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PatientInitials':{
                   'name':'PatientInitials',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PPregnant':{
                   'name':'PPregnant',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WasPAdmittedToHospital':{
                   'name':'WasPAdmittedToHospital',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AEMiscarriage':{
                   'name':'AEMiscarriage',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidTreatSymptoms':{
                   'name':'DidTreatSymptoms',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidPContactHCPAbtSymptoms':{
                   'name':'DidPContactHCPAbtSymptoms',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PatientsHeight':{
                   'name':'PatientsHeight',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PChildAE':{
                   'name':'PChildAE',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AEBirthDefect':{
                   'name':'AEBirthDefect',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMPStartTaking':{
                   'name':'OMPStartTaking',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMIsItTopical':{
                   'name':'OMIsItTopical',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'IsPatientStillExperiencingSymptoms':{
                   'name':'IsPatientStillExperiencingSymptoms',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DrugReaction':{
                   'name':'DrugReaction',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskLastTimeUsed':{
                   'name':'AskLastTimeUsed',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PAnyAllergies':{
                   'name':'PAnyAllergies',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DateOfDeath':{
                   'name':'DateOfDeath',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'ReportedCauseBirthDefect':{
                   'name':'ReportedCauseBirthDefect',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DescPreviousPtSimilarExperience':{
                   'name':'DescPreviousPtSimilarExperience',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMPReason':{
                   'name':'OMPReason',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskPatientDrugQtyUse':{
                   'name':'AskPatientDrugQtyUse',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WhenDidSymptomsEnd':{
                   'name':'WhenDidSymptomsEnd',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidYouGoToER':{
                   'name':'DidYouGoToER',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PatientWeight':{
                   'name':'PatientWeight',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'ReportedCauseMisCarriage':{
                   'name':'ReportedCauseMisCarriage',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AgeOfPatient':{
                   'name':'AgeOfPatient',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WhyPUseProduct':{
                   'name':'WhyPUseProduct',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'PhoneNumber':{
                   'name':'PhoneNumber',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'OMPLastTimeUsed':{
                   'name':'OMPLastTimeUsed',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'WhatDidERDoForP':{
                   'name':'WhatDidERDoForP',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'NameOfHospital':{
                   'name':'NameOfHospital',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'DidSymtomsImproveAfterStop':{
                   'name':'DidSymtomsImproveAfterStop',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AskAnyLabTest':{
                   'name':'AskAnyLabTest',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                },
                'AECausedDeath':{
                   'name':'AECausedDeath',
                   'confirmationStatus':'NONE'
                }
             }
          },
          'dialogState':'STARTED'
       }
    }
```

**Response**

```
{
   'version':'1.0',
   'sessionAttributes':{

   },
   'response':{
      'outputSpeech':{
         'type':'PlainText',
         'text':'Thank you for using the Jane skill. See you next time!'
      },
      'card':{
         'type':'Simple',
         'title':'Jane - Thanks',
         'content':'Thank you for using the Jane skill. See you next time!'
      },
      'reprompt':{
         'outputSpeech':{
            'type':'PlainText',
            'text':None
         }
      },
      'shouldEndSession':True
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The default  Alexa timeout is 8 seconds and it is not configurable.  You can make use of `reprompt` to notify the user to answer. After the initial 8 seconds, `reprompt` will be triggered  which gives the user  another 8 more seconds to respond.

However, you can try some hacks like playing a silent audio for sometime in the background to extend this. But you will have to use the wake-up word "Alexa" in between to give a command or an answer.

And the Lambda time out is different, it is the maximum execution duration per request that comes to your Lambda function.

> In the developer simulator on amazon's website, it works reasonably
>   well without timeout.

A skill session within the Alexa Simulator tab does not time out the way a device would, to give you more time to enter your responses while testing. If your skill keeps the session open, you can close it with "stop."

**shouldEndSession**

This parameter in response JSON must be set to `false` if you want Alexa to start waiting for users response. You should set it to `true` when you actually want to end the session.

```
"shouldEndSession": true
```

More on Response Object [here](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object)

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that Alexa timeout begins after the question ends, right? At the moment where a beep is heard, indicating that the user should speak? If that's the case, why would it time out even on a timely response?

Comment: In order for Alexa to await user response, shouldEndSession should be set to false. Can you check your response and see whether this parameter is there or set to false.  If this is not set to false, session will end right after the response is spoken.

Comment: I have the shouldEndSession set to false before building a response except for in fallback and when the user actually initates a session ending request. In my logs, I get an object stating that the session ended from exceeding max reprompts. I don't have any reprompt code, so there's only one prompt unless the user asks to repeat the question.

Comment: Can you share the request and response JSON for this particular scenario.

Comment: Sure: {'type': 'SessionEndedRequest', 'requestId': 'amzn1.echo-api.request.949b12ca-ab23-40e4-984b-5d0a67c8d3be', 'timestamp': '2018-07-30T15:56:52Z', 'locale': 'en-US', 'reason': 'EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS'}

Comment: The other one is too long by 6492 characters (long questionnaire) so I'll share just the beginning and end of it:

Comment: {'version': '1.0', 'session': {'new': False, 'sessionId': 'amzn1.echo-api.session.omitted', 'application': {'applicationId': 'amzn1.ask.skill.20852205-3919-4d6a-8a62-cb6f8c6214ef'}, 'user': {'userId': 'amzn1.ask.account.omitted'}}, 'context': {'System': {'application': {'applicationId': 'amzn1.ask.skill.omitted'}, 'user': {'userId': 'amzn1.ask.account.omitted'}, 'device': {'deviceId': 'amzn1.ask.device.omitted', 'supportedInterfaces': {}}, 'apiEndpoint': 'https://api.amazonalexa.com', 'apiAccessToken': omitted}},

Comment: 'request': {'type': 'IntentRequest', 'requestId': 'amzn1.echo-api.request.omitted', 'timestamp': '2018-07-30T15:56:15Z', 'locale': 'en-US', 'intent': {'name': 'ScheduleCall', 'confirmationStatus': 'NONE', 'slots': {omitted}}}, 'dialogState': 'STARTED'}}

Comment: sure, the whole object is up there, and the other one above in one comment is complete

Comment: The response is there. I'm sorry for not formatting, I've never used the website before.

Comment: Your response has 'shouldEndSession':True, this means Alexa will terminate the session after the response is spoken.

Comment: That's correct. My confusion arises in that I don't know why a session ended request was raised. I answer the question appropriately and Alexa does nothing with the input.

Comment: Every time when you create a response and you expect an answer from the user or you want the session to be kept alive, then manually set 'shouldEndSession' to false.

Comment: I think this is the case. The only thing that I can think of now, is that in Python, Booleans are represented as False or True, but in JSON, they are lower case. Is there a possibility that this Python dictionary -> JSON conversion is having trouble for this reason? If so, how would one go about the conversion?